# Example of objects which were thought to exist infinitely but later proved to be finite

Tags: soft-question, math-history, big-list

Is there any example of objects which were thought to exist infinitely but later proved to be finite?

I feel like this question was already asked, but I couldn't find the exact duplicate.

**My research:**

[Are there theorems about mathematical objects that are later shown to be nonexistent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277341/are-there-theorems-about-mathematical-objects-that-are-later-shown-to-be-nonexis): This question is similar to mine, and it offers a great answer, but still does not answer my question exactly.

[What are some actually finite sequences that long thought to be infinite?](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/ir8wrb/what_are_some_actually_finite_sequences_that_long/)(on Reddit) : It indeed answers my question, but I would like more examples, not just about sequences.

Comment: Well anything which is conjectured to have countable cardinality can be arranged as a sequence; and it is unlikely (not impossible of course) that some class was conjectured to be *un*countable but later shown to be finite. So your second link exhausts a bigger class of examples than you might think.

Comment: Hard to imagine examples...

Comment: In a sense, "Western math" began in Ancient Greece with the discovery that purported finite "processes" (measuring) give rise to infinite processes.